# Can I exclude a item from a list but not remove it from the list itself?

Tags: python

Say I have a list

```
List = ['bob', 'john', 'mary', 'jill']
```

I want to pass the list to a function but I do not want john to be part of the list that is passed. I do not want to permentaly remove it, just exclude it when being passed.

Is this possible? All the examples of pop/remove I saw removed it from the list. I know I can make a copy and remove it, but I thought I'd ask to see if something like this exists within python already.

Comment: You can pass a *new* list to the function that doesn't include `john`. E.g, `myfunc([name for name in List if name != 'john'])`.

Comment: Y ou'll have to be much more detailed about what semantics you expect for "exclude" when you pass the list, and how those semantics differ from simply constructing the list you *do* want to process.

Comment: Copying/filtering is the normal way to do it. There is no generic facility to mask a value in a list. Copying lists is pretty fast. Do you need the original list postions (for instance, maybe the index of the values is important)? Then maybe a pandas dataframe would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "temporarily" remove something and expect it to be back automatically. The only two possibilities are to remove and then put back later, or to make a duplicate data structure.

Unless order matters, I would likely construct a `frozenset` from the `list`, then make a new `frozenset` without the desired element, especially if you will do it in the loop:

```
full_list = ['bob', 'john', 'mary', 'jill']
full_set = frozenset(List)

no_john_set = full_set - {'john'}   # frozenset({'bob', 'mary', 'jill'})
```

Comment: If you want it short, you may use set instead of frozenset: `list ( set(a) - {'john'} )`. But using sets might be dangerous in case you got duplicate entries. Lets say you got two times `'bob'` within your list it reduces to one with the `set()` call

Answer (score 2):

As larsks [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110794/can-i-exclude-a-item-from-a-list-but-not-remove-it-from-the-list-itself#comment116883301_66110794) in the comments, you can pass a new list to the function you wish to call without changing the original list:

```
lst = ['bob', 'john', 'mary', 'jill']
def x(lstp):
    for i in lstp:
        print(i)
x([name for name in lst if name != 'john'])
```

The above code will print:

```
bob
mary
jill
```

and exclude `'john'`.

The above program creates a new list to be passed as a parameter to `myfunc`, then iterates over `lst`, adding each item from it to the new list, if the statement `if name != 'john'` evaluates to True, which, of course, occurs only if the item in the list is not `'john'`.